# Which is more efficient? lg(n+10^n) higher than 2^lgn

Tags: asymptotics

Based on the order by asymptotic growth rate which is more efficient?

Comment: It could depend on what base log you are using. Could you be more specific in the question?

Comment: it is base log 2

Comment: If it is base 2 then the second term might as well be n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+10^n)}{2^{\log(n)}}$. This is

$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+10^n)}{2^{\log(n)}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n+1+10^{n+1})-\log(n+10^n)}{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{(n+1)+10^{n+1}}{n+10^n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(\frac{(n+1)/10^n+10}{n/10^n+1}\right)\\
&=\log(10)\\
&>1
\end{align}$$

where the first equation was using [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (L'Hospital for sequences).

That this limit is larger than $1$ implies that for $n$ large enough $\log(n+10^n)$ becomes larger than $2^{\log(n)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking:

$\begin{align*}
  \log_2 (2^n)
     &= n \\
  \log_2(10^n + n)
     &> \log_2(10^n) \\
     &= n \log_2 10
\end{align*}$

As $\log_2 10 = 3.3219$, the later is larger.

For rough comparisons, you can discard "lower terms" with impunity. In any case, often "asymptotic growth rate" applies only for very large $n$, and is usually meant to hide constant factors (check e.g. Hildebrand's ["Short Course on Asymptotics"](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehildebr/lecture-notes/asymptotics.pdf) for details on the notation and manipulation techniques). If so, both are $\Theta(n)$, and more details are needed to compare fairly.

Comment: The last but one equality statement is false